# Third level selection from database

Tags: jquery, mysql

I am trying to select data from third level of selection box i.e when i select any  option from first selection box then second selection box appears and it has the options related to the selected option from the first selection box and till now, all working good. Now i am trying to go one level more i.e. when i select option from second selection box, the third selection box will appear and it contains the options related to the second selection box. All the data in second and third selection boxes coming from the databases.

Here is my code :-

```
     <select id="options" class="form-control">
        <option>--</option>                                         
        <option value="1">Real Estate</option>
        <option value="2">Automobiles</option>
    </select><br> 

    <select id="content-1" class="content hidden form-control" >
        <?php                
        $result = "SELECT * FROM sub_categories where categories_name ='Real Estate'"; 
        $data =mysqli_query ($conn, $result);               

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data))
         { ?> 

         <option><?php echo $row['sub_categories_name'];?></option>
        <?php }?>
    </select>


    <select id="content-2" class="content hidden form-control" >
        <?php                
        $result = "SELECT * FROM sub_categories where categories_name ='Automobiles'"; 
        $data =mysqli_query ($conn, $result);                 

         while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data))
         { ?> 

         <option><?php echo $row['sub_categories_name'];?></option>
         <?php }?>
  </select>
```

Here is js :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#options").change(function(){
                    $(".content").addClass("hidden");
                    $("#content-"+$(this).val()).removeClass("hidden");
                });
            });
        </script>
```

for demo here is my static two level selection box in which i want to add the third level selection box. Please help me out, i am poorly trapped in it. here is the link 
http://jsfiddle.net/Bhawesh7731/6mphs2gn/

Comment: Sorry but this code does not do anything like what you are claiming!

Comment: To make this work, you would have to be using some AJAX code to populate the second and third dropdowns. You are not showing us anything like that, this is all hard coded and selecting a different value in dropdown 1 would have no effect on the other dropdowns

Comment: I can only assume you are hoping someone here will write all the necessary code for you. Pro tip: we're a bit different on Stack Overflow from other sources of help on the internet. 
Beginners are welcome, but we expect a certain amount of effort to be expended on a question prior to a question being posted. 
That is undoubtedly more time and effort for question authors, but we dont write code for you although we are very willing to 
help you fix issues with code you have written.

Comment: here is my three level static code:- http://jsfiddle.net/Bhawesh7731/e6muzhvt/

Comment: Well that is NOT what you posted in your question

Answer (score 0):

the thing is you can get what you want in your question is through ajax meanwhile if you want to go the way you are going

change the third select box class "content" to "content1" in my case and 
try this script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#options").change(function(){
      $(".content").addClass("hidden");
    $("#content-"+$(this).val()).removeClass("hidden");
    openAnother($(this).val());
 });
});

function openAnother(val){
       $("#content-"+val).change(function(){
       $(".content1").addClass("hidden");
       $("#content-"+$(this).val()).removeClass("hidden");
    });
  }
```